# Firefox "auto-complete" is very slow

Tags: firefox, performance, autocomplete, sqlite

Firefox version: 3.6

My `places.sqlite` is rather big (114MB, after being optimized by SpeedyFox.)  If I turn on auto-complete, it may take 1 or 2 seconds for Firefox to accept a newly typed URL. To reproduce the issue:

1. Type a URL into the URL bar, press enter.
2. Nothing happens, and Firefox consumes 100% CPU (actually 50% of 2 cores) for 1 to 2 seconds
3. Then Firefox start the network connection and load the webpage.

Since it consumes 100% CPU, I don't think the bottleneck is the disk.  I have some experience with SQLite and I know a 100MB DB is very small.  To achieve the delay Firefox must be doing some expensive processing or inefficient queries.

The issue does not appear if:

1. auto-complete is turned off, or
2. the URL is frequently used, or
3. a new profile with no history is used

Does anyone have any idea how to solve the problem?  Should I file this as a bug?  I don't want to give up my 100MB history, but I don't want to give up auto-complete either :)

Comment: Huh, just came across this because for the last two or three months I've been noticing Firefox is taking more than the usual amount of time to autocomplete.  My habit is to type 2-3 letters and hit enter, but for the last several weeks this is just google searching those 2-3 letters now.  I have to sit and wait a couple of seconds if I want it to prefill the address bar. It is still very fast, but it doesn't take much latency to completely break the UX.

Answer (score 1):

Try this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13878 | It is not a bug, 'its a feature'. ;) There is an other addon, but you may have to edit its compat info to make it work with 3.6. If you dont know how, just ask. >> https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11198

Comment: The add-on you've mentioned is similar to SpeedyFox. Basically they both execute "VACUUM" on the sqlite3 database. The problem that I'm talking about is the (probably avoidable) inefficiency in auto-complete. Does it make sense?

Comment: To be honest I experienced this 1-2second problem, WHEN I installed some new addons and themes. Could you try this out on a new profile? (Of course bringing your places file, but leaving the other stuff.)